# Unable to call apendChild method in IE8

Tags: javascript

Hi i am trying to load jquery file dynamically, i used the following the code and get 
  executed in FF & IE9, coming to IE8 it throws the following Error, can any body suggest me
  how to solve this problem.

```
Error:
SCRIPT65535: Unexpected call to method or property access. 
Effecta.ObjectComparator_v1.1.1.js, line 32 character 5
```

The Code i wrote is as follows :

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js", false);
    req.onreadystatechange = function(){            
        if (req.readyState == 4) {              
            var script = document.createElement("script");
            script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(req.responseText)); // line 32
            document.head.appendChild(script);          
        }
    };
    req.send(null);
```

thanks in advance

Comment: That error doesn't really seem to be related to the posted code ?

Comment: i gave the name for what purpose i used this code, I changed the title, Thanks for your suggestion,

Comment: You might be running afoul of browser support, IE8 is spotty.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Browser_Compatibility  But since you have the src and are generating a script tag, you could simply append a correct tag immediately rather than loading its content.

Comment: One has to wonder why on earth you would use ajax for this, and not just insert the script tag directly ?

Comment: I dont have much knowledge how to add jQuery file dynamically i found this working solution after googling, can u please share the optimized code snippet that will help me alot

Answer (score 1):

You creating a cross domain `XMLHttpRequest` request. IE8 only supports those in very limited conditions.

Instead, create a script tag and set its `src` property to the url.

Stealing from how Google does its injection in analytics:

```
(function(d, script) {
    script = d.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.async = true;
    script.onload = function(){
        // remote script has loaded
    };
    script.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js';
    d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}(document));
```

Comment: Hi your code is working fine in IE, but in FF throws the following error. i used this one EffectaJQ = jQuery.noConflict( true ); and EffectaJQ('*').on('click', function(e) {}); Error : TypeError: EffectaJQ(...).on is not a function

Comment: This is unrelated to the script above. If you want it synchronous and in the start, you can do `document.write('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js')` but really that's almost never a good idea. You should learn about how the JavaScript concurrency model works.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 doesn't have `document.head` property, try `document.getElementsByTagName['head'][0];`

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, i made changes but still it is showing the same error at the above line of document.getElementsByTagName['head'][0]

Comment: What's the actual value and type of `req.responseText`?

Comment: req.responseText gave me a jQuery file as text

Comment: Though Benjamin has given a correct way to do this, you can also try to set `script.text = req.responseText` instead of trying to create a textNode.

Comment: Hi his code is working fine in IE, but in FF throws the following error. i used this one EffectaJQ = jQuery.noConflict( true ); and EffectaJQ('*').on('click', function(e) {}); Error : TypeError: EffectaJQ(...).on is not a function